# Why is my state not updating in redux when clicking button

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am trying to update my redux state but it seems to not update when when clicking the button. I have a 'teams' drop down and when clicking the 'add team' button it should update with static data being 'team 1' and 'team 2' however it does not update. Apologies for the amount of code im new to redux and have no idea where the issue could be. code below:

Store.ts

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

/* FILE DEPENDENCIES */
import RootReducer from './rootReducer';

//Fix dev tools
const Store = createStore(RootReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

export type RootStore = ReturnType<typeof RootReducer>;

export default Store;
```

teamsReducer.ts

```
import { Team } from '../Models/TeamsModels';
import { TeamsDispatchTypes, TEAMS_FAIL, TEAMS_LOADING, TEAMS_SUCCESS } from './Actions/TeamsActionTypes';

export interface IDefaultState {
    loading: boolean;
    teams?: Team[];
}

const defaultState: IDefaultState = {
    loading: false,
};

const teamsReducer = (state: IDefaultState = defaultState, action: TeamsDispatchTypes): IDefaultState => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case TEAMS_FAIL:
            return {
                loading: false,
                teams: state.teams,
            };
        case TEAMS_LOADING:
            return {
                loading: true,
                teams: state.teams,
            };
        case TEAMS_SUCCESS:
            return {
                loading: false,
                teams: action.payload,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default teamsReducer;
```

TeamsActions.ts

```
import { Dispatch } from 'redux';
import { Team } from '../../Models/TeamsModels';
/*FILE DEPENDENCIES*/
import { TeamsDispatchTypes, TEAMS_FAIL, TEAMS_SUCCESS } from './TeamsActionTypes';

export const GetTeams = () => (dispatch: Dispatch<TeamsDispatchTypes>) => {
    try {
        const newPayload: Team[] = [{ name: 'Team 1' }, { name: 'Team 2' }];

        dispatch({
            type: TEAMS_SUCCESS,
            payload: newPayload,
        });
    } catch (e) {
        dispatch({
            type: TEAMS_FAIL,
        });
    }
};
```

TeamActionTypes.ts

```
import { Team } from '../../Models/TeamsModels';

export const TEAMS_LOADING = 'TEAMS_LOADING';
export const TEAMS_SUCCESS = 'TEAMS_SUCCESS';
export const TEAMS_FAIL = 'TEAMS_FAIL';

export interface TeamsLoading {
    type: typeof TEAMS_LOADING;
}

export interface TeamsSuccess {
    type: typeof TEAMS_SUCCESS;
    payload: Team[];
}

export interface TeamsFail {
    type: typeof TEAMS_FAIL;
}

export type TeamsDispatchTypes = TeamsLoading | TeamsFail | TeamsSuccess;
```

rootReducer.ts

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

/*FILE DEPENDENCIES*/
import TeamsReducer from './Teams/teamsReducer';

const RootReducer = combineReducers({
    teams: TeamsReducer,
});

export default RootReducer;
```

index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './Component/App/App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Store from './State/Store';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={Store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'),
);

reportWebVitals();
```

App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from '../Navbar/Navbar';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';

function App(): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Router>
                <Navbar></Navbar>
                <Switch></Switch>
            </Router>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Navbar.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import '../Navbar/Navbar.css';

import { RootStore } from '../../State/Store';
import { GetTeams } from '../../State/Teams/Actions/TeamsActions';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

export default function Navbar(): JSX.Element {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const teamsState = useSelector((state: RootStore) => state.teams);

    //Is not updating store, need to look at this
    const handleOnClick = () => {
        dispatch(GetTeams());
    };

    console.log('Teams State: ', teamsState);
    return (
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <NavLink className="navbar-brand" to="/">
                Navbar
            </NavLink>
            <button
                className="navbar-toggler"
                type="button"
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
                aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown"
                aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation"
            >
                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                <ul className="navbar-nav">
                    <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a
                            className="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                            href="#"
                            id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                            data-toggle="dropdown"
                            aria-haspopup="true"
                            aria-expanded="false"
                        >
                            Dropdown link
                        </a>
                        <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <a className="dropdown-item" href="/add-team" onClick={handleOnClick}>
                                Add Team
                            </a>
                            {teamsState.teams &&
                                teamsState.teams.map((team) => (
                                    <a className="dropdown-item" href={'/' + team.name} key={team.name}>
                                        {team.name}
                                    </a>
                                ))}
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
}
```

Comment: I recommend you add a bunch of console.logs and determine where it is not executing. That would help us out a alot

Comment: In the redux devtools you can find what actions are dispatched and what changes they make to the state. That should be the first place to look and when posting a question that should be the information added to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that the action gets dispatched and the teams are saved in the state but then the whole page immediately refreshes and the data is lost.  This is because your "Add Team" is an `a` element with an `href` tag, so clicking that link calls `handleOnClick` but it also causes navigation.  Since you are using just an `a` and not a `Link` from react-router-dom, that navigation event is not handled properly.

The teams started showing up as soon as I removed the `href` from the "Add Team" link, though it's not a good practice to use `a` if it's not a link so you should use a `div` or some other HTML element instead. Clicking on an individual team name still has the same issue of lost data due to clicking an `a` tag so you will want to use a `Link` there.